# Missing first ViewController in the stack after popViewControllerAnimated()

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

Being in third controller in the Stack (ReleaseCaptureVC)

```
"<DashboardViewController: 0x7f9788ed80a0>",
"<ChargeDetailViewController2: 0x7f978b072a00>",
"<ReleaseCaptureViewController: 0x7f978a0f39f0>"
```

I am doing  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated]

Immediately after this command current controller is properly removed from the stack and I am seeing the ChargeDetailViewController2

```
"<DashboardViewController: 0x7f9788ed80a0>",
"<ChargeDetailViewController2: 0x7f978b072a00>"
```

Now when trying to return one step back from now, I discover that the first VC has disappeared from the stack:

""

How can it happen and at which point?

Answer (score 0):

Root cause found - other code involved has been explicitely removing one of controllers in stack. So no system issue.